# Cube bike cassette wobble

Tags: cassette, wobble

Recently I have bought a used 2012 Cube CLS LTD PRO hybrid bike in a good condition . The only thing was the rear cassette a little wobbling. I asked a mechanic about this and he told that almost every bike has this problem . After riding about 300 km I noticed that the cassette is wobbling more than it had been. Today I took the rear wheel off and saw that the cassette had a tiny backlash on the wheel . Can I fix the wobble simply by tightening the cassette , or should I buy a new one ?

Comment: What do you mean by "backlash on the wheel"?

Comment: the cassette has a little play on the rear hub

Comment: THAT should not happen. If the cassette is already fairly tight, check whether the cassette is even compatible with the freewheel.

Comment: It sounds like the cassette is falling apart, or has been misthreaded.

Comment: "backlash" refers to "gear backlash": which is a jerking effect caused by free play in a moving transmission; it is not a synonym for free play itself.

Comment: I don't think you can fix the problem by tightening the casette, since it sounds like the hub has free play. You have to tighten the hub, not to tighten the sprockets against the hub (which is what I understand by "tighten the casette"). The casette is not moving around on the hub, right?

Answer (score 2):

Wobbling cassettes should be absent from, not present on, every bike. It is possible that the wobble is caused by worn splines on what might be a soft (aluminium, as opposed to steel) freehub. I myself recently blogged about such an issue at http://bit.ly/HubTrouble .

The wobble might instead be a result of an incorrectly seated lock-ring, or a missing spacer from behind the cassette (in which case you might find this link of interest: http://bit.ly/CassetteIssues)